# how to echo this image code in php?

Tags: php, syntax-error

i want to echo this image in an php echo code

```
<p style="border-bottom:#666 dotted 1px;"><?  echo '<a style="text-decoration:none" href="' . $site . $url . '">' ;?><img style="border:#2489ce solid 1px;" src="http://www.balkanweb.com/foto/<?=$vlerat['Id_Foto']; ?>" width="100%" alt=""></a></p>
```

example but with error .

```
 echo '<li>';
      echo '<a style="text-decoration:none" href="' . $site . $url . '"> '; 
      echo trim(strip_tags(str_replace('<', ' <', $vlerat['Titolo'])));  

      echo '<p style="border-bottom:#666 dotted 1px;">&nbsp;</p>';
       echo '<p style="border-bottom:#666 dotted 1px;">';
    echo '<a style="text-decoration:none" href="' . $site . $url . '">' ;
    echo '<img style="border:#2489ce solid 1px;" src="http://www.balkanweb.com/foto/<?=$vlerat[Id_Foto]" width="100%" alt="">';
       echo '</a></p>';
       echo '</a></li>';
       } ?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: it doesnt show the image , i think the problem is <?=$vlerat['Id_Foto']; ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an errant `<?=` in your code:

```
src="http://www.balkanweb.com/foto/<?=$vlerat[Id_Foto]" width="100%" alt="">'
                                 ^^^^^^
                                  HERE
```

Try:

```
echo '<img style="border:#2489ce solid 1px;" src="http://www.balkanweb.com/foto/' . $vlerat[Id_Foto] . '" width="100%" alt="">'
```

Comment: how to fix it ? please